# How to insert a column in an existing excel on Sikuli python?

Tags: python, excel, sikuli

I want to insert a column in an existing excel on Sikuli python ?

Comment: Please add some information about what you have already tried.

Comment: @KevinMüller I am haven't idea for this problem. if you can resolve it, can you help me? thanks

Comment: [This Tutorial](https://codoid.com/read-write-excel-using-python/) may help you

Comment: @KevinMüller thank you, but I work on Sikuli, your method can't run with it!

Comment: Are you opening the excel document or are you trying to add it while closed? May I see your code on what you currently have or would you just like an answer on what I think you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use excellibrary to add column ,
Do by using pandas in python and then import that file to robot framework